# it;s showing constraint specification not allowed here

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table Bill (
BillNo  NUMBER PRIMARY KEY,
StoreName varchar2(20) constraint bill_sname_fk reference Store(StoreName),
Shopperid NUMBER constraint bill_sis_fk reference Shopper(ShopperId),
ArCode CHAR(5) constraint bill_acode_fk reference Article(ArCode),
Amount NUMBER,
BillDate DATE,
Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 1 constraint bill q_ck check(Quantity>1)
);
```

difference between

1. `Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 1 constraint bill q_ck check(Quantity>1)`
2. `Quantity NUMBER(4) DEFAULT 1 check(Quantity>1)`

Comment: The name of the constraint needs to be a single identifier. If you want to put a space in it, put backticks around it: ```constraint `bill q_ck` check(quantity > 1)```

Comment: Your default quantity doesn't fit the constraint. Maybe you mean `>=1`?

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL, not SQL-Server? MySQL doesn't have data types `varchar2` and `NUMBER`.

Comment: I'd rather expect Oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Data-Types.html#GUID-7B72E154-677A-4342-A1EA-C74C1EA928E6, varchar2 and number are both found.

Comment: `bill q_ck` is an invalid constraint name. Try `bill_q_ck` or `"bill q_ck"`.